# Accesing MySql Database for 3 different tabs using PHP queries

Tags: php, mysql, tabs

I Have 3 different tabs for different searches having search box in html. i am trying to access database for these search tabs. I have wrote PHP code for all three tabs in an another page. But the problem occurring is that it is providing result for only single tab at a time. we tried to give id's to div tags in PHP page but its not working, please suggest suitable answer.

```
 <div class="nav-tabs-custom">
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
 <li class="active"><a href="#tab_1-1" data-toggle="tab" id="tab1">Keyword Search</a></li>
 <li><a href="#tab_2-2" data-toggle="tab" id="tab2">Boolean Search</a></li>
 <li><a href="#tab_3-3" data-toggle="tab" id="tab3">Candidate Search</a></li>
</ul>
The PHP code Is in another page. The Text boxes is in same HTML page 
<div class="tab-content">
<div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_1-1">
<form action="viewcandidate.php" method="Post" name="seachcompany1">
<input type="text" id="keyword_s_any" name="keyword_s_any" >
</form>
```

PHP code As Follows:-

```
<?
$candname=($_POST['candi_s_by_code']); 
$candmail=($_POST['candi_s_by_mail']);
$candphone=($_POST['candi_s_by_phone'];
?>
<div id="tab_1-1">
<?if(isset($_POST['candi_s_by_code'])){
$sql="SELECT  * FROM candidate WHERE cand_number=$candname";
} 
?>
</div>
<div id="tab_2-2">
<?else if(isset($_POST['candi_s_by_mail'])){
$sql="SELECT  * FROM candidate WHERE cand_mail='$candmail'";}
?>
</div>
<div id="tab_3-3">
<?else if(isset($_POST['candi_s_by_phone'])){                                                                          
$sql="SELECT  * FROM candidate WHERE cand_mobile=$candphone";}
?>
```

How to active the tabs and  fire the right query written for it. The logic[query] of all three tabs is written on same page.
Suggest some skeleton or links or code logic. Thank you.

Comment: please mention php or ajax code over here.

Comment: check if you are getting any data in `$_POST['candi_s_by_mail']` and in `$_POST['candi_s_by_phone']` . By the way, how you are getting these post request?

Comment: We are getting it Through textboxes. All values of tabs are working with data,But One tab at a time.

Comment: You didn't show submit button in your code. How the form is submitted? How many forms do you have on the page?

Comment: we have submit button but we can't drag all code here,
We have 3 forms for 3 tabs. every form with a a submit button.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is not at the result Php provides, it is in the search parameters.  When tab-1 is active $candmail and $candphone are really not set.  They don't have a value. Respectively, when tab-2 is active $candname and $candphone don't have values.  The values in non active tab pages are not Posted.
You must set a mechanism to make them available in active tab. Like post them in a hidden field, or something.  All three forms must be submitted, one by one and data tranfered in hidden fields, from each form, to the next.
It depends on your implementation of the three forms.

Comment: do you have any idea about how to active all tabs and  post the values.

Comment: You can't have three active tabs simultaneously. All forms must be submitted, but the third submit must be the one who will post the data to Php. In previous submits you just store the values, in session variable, or in hidden fields.

Comment: @IgorGreg..If it can't be made active all at a time...what can be the solution so the the query written for the tabs can be fired correctly. I mean correct query for correct tab [active tab]. We tried by passing the  id of submit button..but it din't worked.